# How to track Google Analytics from a specific page on my website

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, statistics

I have a website that has a sign up form and login form (besides other pages, obviously).
The sign up flow for goes as this:

Landing page > SignUp Form > Thank you Page (Button click) > Login Page

I would like to find out and/or track the number of users that enter the login page from from the Thank you page.

Please note that the "Thank you page" cannot be modified. It's a long story why not but it can't be edited.

I have a Google Analytics account tracking all the traffic. 
Could anyone please point me whether this information (stats about the thank you page being the referring page for the login page) is already available out of the box in GA? If so, how would I access the information?

If this info is not available, how can I set up (preferably) goals for tracking my conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You should set up a [Goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en).

The goal should be {Thank you page URL} -> {Login page URL}. This does not require any code at all to be implemented in your page.